# How to bind the same event to different buttons in different frame

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I coded an app with different frames. In each frame, there is a button that I want to bind to the return button of the keyboard. When I am on a specific frame, I want to press 'Return button' and the button return to the specific function.

I tried `frame.bind` but it does not work.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root=Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")


def enter_frame1(event=None):
    Label(my_frame1, text="Say hi").pack()

def enter_frame2(event=None):
    Label(my_frame2, text="Be Happy").pack()

my_notebook=ttk.Notebook(root)
my_notebook.pack(pady=15)

my_frame1= Frame(my_notebook, width=500, height=500)
my_frame2= Frame(my_notebook, width=500, height=500)

my_frame1.pack()
my_frame2.pack()

my_notebook.add(my_frame1, text=1)
my_notebook.add(my_frame2, text=2)

Button(my_frame1, text='Enter', command=enter_frame1).pack()
Button(my_frame2, text='Enter', command=enter_frame2).pack()

my_frame1.bind('<Return>', enter_frame1)
my_frame2.bind('<Return>', enter_frame2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should set the focus to that specific key. See [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-focus_set-and-focus_get-method/).

Comment: See my edit pls

Comment: Change `def enter_frame1(event)` to `def enter_frame1(event=None)`. Do the same for `enter_frame2`

Comment: But when I press Enter button there is no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add below 2 lines of code before root.mainloop()

```
my_frame1.focus()
my_frame2.focus()
```

Please write in a comment is it desired result that you are looking for?